# How to validate Variables before setting it up in Session or request

Tags: java, validation, variables

### How to validate Variables before setting it up in Session or request (JAVA)?

I have used **IBM appscan** Source on my web application.
I am facing issue at **validation.required** defects.

It's giving me error at lines where i am setting variable in session or request.
Example:

```
userSession.setAttribute("fileName",fileName);
userSession.setAttribute("mxXml",mxXml);
```

I want to know how can I validate this variables so my scan report wont get this errors.

Comment: session variable should not give errors... even if you set null value to a session variable.

Comment: actully its security check of source code.so it scans for all loopholes in coding,its asking for validating it before setting it in session